# Placing timeout for SSLSocket handshake

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, soap, tcp

Recently, I am having trouble with our SOAP calls which uses apache axis 1.4. I have set the timeout as 30s, however it sometimes reaches around ~1000s before throwing an exception. After exploring internal implementation of axis, I found out that it is due to the SSLSocket handshake.

See sample error below.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.$$YJP$$socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
```

Is it possible to put a timeout also on the handshake? Or is there another way to forcibly cut the connection.

Also, see the handshake part on the code

```
 sslSocket = sslFactory.createSocket(tunnel, host, port, true);
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(Messages.getMessage("setupTunnel00",
                          tcp.getProxyHost(),
                        "" + tunnelPort));
            }
        }

        ((SSLSocket) sslSocket).startHandshake();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `tunnel`, call:

```
tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 30000);
```

Comment: @CesarLoachamin that is not what a review is for.  Downvote the answer if you think the content is incorrect.  As far as I can see it is not an example of _"critique"_

Comment: @Eldon Hipolito I haven't seen where you set the timeout. Did you set the timeout of ```tunnel```?

Comment: Honestly, apache axis sets the timeout after the handshake of the ssl socket.