# Is there a recommended way of establishing an SSLSocket connection to to a peer with a timeout on the handshake process

Tags: ssl, networking, bouncycastle, java-11

I have read some answers which do not resolve my question fully e.g. [Placing timeout for SSLSocket handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49441183/8928797). This answer requires me to layer a plaintext socket under an SSLSocket which I would rather not do if there is an alternative. The relevant part of my code is as follows (FYI I'm not hardcoding passwords its just for testing):

```
private static SSLSocket establishConnection(InetAddress ipv4, int port) {

    try {

        int ksn = Stub.getKeystoreNum();
        SecurityUtilities su = new SecurityUtilities("truststore" + ksn + ".jks", "keystore" + ksn + ".jks", "trustcert", "mykey");

        KeyStore keystore = su.loadKeyStore("password".toCharArray());
        KeyStore truststore = su.loadTrustStore("password".toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KEY_MANAGER);
        keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KEY_MANAGER);
        trustManagerFactory.init(truststore);

        // specify TLS version e.g. TLSv1.3
        SSLContext serverContext = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS_VERSION);
        serverContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), SecureRandom.getInstance(RNG_ALGORITHM, RNG_PROVIDER));

        // THIS CODE IS MY ATTEMPT AT ESTABLISHING AN SSLSOCKET WITH A TIMEOUT
        SSLSocketFactory fact = serverContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) fact.createSocket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipv4.getHostAddress(), port), CON_TIMEOUT);
        return socket;

    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("tls node connection failed");
    }

    return null;
}
```

My code successfully establishes a connection and having tested it with tcpdump I found that it does indeed seem to encrypt the data transmitted with it. However because I have read that it's not possible to create an SSLSocket without having it immediately connect e.g.

```
return (SSLSocket) fact.createSocket(ipv4.getHostAddress(), port);
```

and because the connect method is defined in Socket and not SSLSocket I feel I am making some kind of mistake. additionally I have seen multiple examples which utilize the **SSLSocket.startHandshake()** method is this necessary as I have successfully established connections with the previous line of code alone?

Thanks for any help